# is it required to install TF Slim externally after pulling a docker image latest-devel-gpu(r0.10)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it required to install **TF Slim** externally after pulling a docker image latest-devel-gpu(r0.10) for GPU environment?
when I do import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim it gives me an error:

> "No module named Slim" through python.

Comment: Can you post more information? Slim is in contrib which is included with the default tensorflow packaging. How are you importing it, and what does the stacktrace look like?

Comment: @Alexandre I ran ipython in command line, and trying to check whether TF-slim is installed or not using - import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim, it shows me "Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named slim

Comment: I noticed that in the path tensorflow.contrib there is no folder named slim in the docker container I am using. But I am surprised why it is not there ? what is the way to check which is the version of tensorflow docker image I am using like (r0.10 or 0.11 ...) ?

Comment: The documentation in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/docker has instructions on pulling the latest version (last code snippet).

Comment: @Alexandre, I did it by updating the docker image to 0.10.0-devel-gpu, which has full version of TF-Slim

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace? If you do import tensorfow as tf; tf.contrib.slim it should work.

Comment: It is working after updating the docker image to the tag I just mentioned above (0.10.0-devel-gpu). Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

OP self-solved problem by upgrading to the docker tag 0.10.0-devel-gpu (and it should work going forward).